# Using regex inside if clause in bash

Tags: bash, regular-expression

Look at this if block:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="m.m"
if [[ "${str}" =~ "m\.m" ]]; then
    echo "matched"
else
    echo "not matched"
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

This should print "matched", but it doesn't. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to remove the quoting in the regex match.

```
if [[ ${str} =~ m\.m ]]; then
```

From the bash man page:

> [...] An  additional  binary operator, =~, is available, with the same
>                 precedence as == and !=.  When it is used,  the  string  to  the
>                 right  of the operator is considered an extended regular expres‐
>                 sion and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).  The return value
>                 is 0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.  If the
>                 regular expression is syntactically incorrect,  the  conditional
>                 expression's return value is 2.  If the shell option nocasematch
>                 is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of
>                 alphabetic characters.  **Any part of the pattern may be quoted to
>                 force it to be matched  as  a  string.**

So with the quotes, you're using good-old string matching.

If you need spaces in the pattern, just escape them:

```
str="m   m"
if [[ ${str} =~ m\ +m ]]; then
```

Comment: but with no double quote, we can not use space character in regex pattern. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Space should be escaped like `\ `.

Comment: If I want to find a string that ends with a dynamic number should use `${str} =~ "needle"[0-9]{1}` or should I use `${str} =~ needle[0-9]{1}`?