# Pattern matching

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, patterns

I am trying to follow Bash Cookbook to learn about Bash Scripting. I am on example 6.8 Testing with Regular Expression.

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# cookbook filename: trackmatch

for CDTRACK in *
do
     if [[ "$CDTRACK" =~ "([[:alpha:][:blank:]]*)- ([[:digit:]]*) - (.*)$" ]]
then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
else
    echo Error $CDTRACK
fi
done
```

I apply this to a couple of files in my directory:

*Ludwig van Beethovern - 02 - Adagio un poco mosso.ogg*

*Ludwig van Beethovern - 01 - Allegro.ogg*

I always get an error returned. The issue appears to be with `([[:alpha:][:blank:]]*)- ([[:digit:]]*) -` section of code. When I do have the if statement as: `if [[ "$CDTRACK" =~ "(.*)$" ]]` then there is no error.

Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

I am running the code on AWS, Bash v 4.2

Comment: try \- instead of - ? and "\s" instead of " " ?

Comment: Will do, but if I try `([[:ascii:]]*)` it also doesn't work so I don't think that is the issue ...

Comment: Related: [Using regex inside if clause in bash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32119/using-regex-inside-if-clause-in-bash)

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to the question, but you spelled [Beethoven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_van_Beethoven) wrong

Answer (score 6):

[ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) is a good start for bash programming. It gives quite useful hints:

```
Line 6:
if [[ "$CDTRACK" =~ "([[:alpha:][:blank:]]*)- ([[:digit:]]*) - (.*)$" ]]
                    ^-- SC2076: Don't quote rhs of =~, it'll match literally rather than as a regex.
```

Regex can't be quoted like this. Working example with escaped special characters (basically spaces):

```
if [[ "$CDTRACK" =~ ([[:alpha:][:blank:]]*)-\ ([[:digit:]]*)\ -\ (.*)$ ]]
```

or as *glenn jackman* proposed, quoting only the other characters (which looks weird for people using different languages, but works too):

```
if [[ "$CDTRACK" =~ ([[:alpha:][:blank:]]*)"- "([[:digit:]]*)" - "(.*)$ ]]
```

Oneliner to test against existing string:

```
if [[ "Ludwig van Beethovern - 02 - Adagio un poco mosso.ogg" =~ ([[:alpha:][:blank:]]*)-\ ([[:digit:]]*)\ -\ (.*)$ ]]; then echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"; fi
```

Comment: Great answer. Alternately: `([[:alpha:][:blank:]]*)"- "([[:digit:]]*)" - "(.*)$` --  I like to use quotes for the literal bits

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks. Added as possible option. Learning something new every day (while forgetting other things). I can't decide which option looks more weird ...

Comment: Personally, I prefer quoting over backslashing.

Comment: reading bash cookbook led me here. i prefer escaping spaces.