# Working regex does not match in bash

Tags: bash, shell, regular-expression

i have a CIDR range in this regex

```
^5\.188\.62\.([1-9]?\d|[12]\d\d)$
```

I am able to confirm matching values using https://regexr.com

Now i am testing some code and i am using the following as a sample to test matches

```
 var='^5\.188\.62\.111';[[ $var =~ '^5\.188\.62\.([1-9]?\d|[12]\d\d)$' ]] && echo yes || echo no
```

In final, i am not able to get it working.

Any tip to solve?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `var=5.188.62.212`?

Comment: When using `=~`, don't quote the thing on the right

Comment: When answering questions, don't answer in the comments ;) (@AndyDalton) -- perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32119/117549 ?

Comment: See also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) - in particular, note that `\d` is a PCRE element

Comment: FWIW `[[ $var =~ '^5\.188\.62\.([1-9]?\d|[12]\d\d)$' ]]` would be OK (and would match on `var=5.188.62.111`) in `zsh` instead of `bash` after `set -o rematchpcre`.