# WHILE LOOP to prompt user to enter the correct number

Tags: bash

I am very new to Unix (BASH) and I need help with validating/checking user's number input to make sure they have entered:

1. A number that starts with a 4, and
2. The number is exactly three (3) digits in length

Currently, I am still trying to get #1 to work and I am already having trouble, any advice on how to proceed with this?

My Code:

```
echo "Please enter a three digit code that starts with '4':"
while read $input
do
    if $input = '^[4]*'; then
        echo "Your code started with 4"
    else
        echo "Invalid"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Welcome! Start looking for the correct syntax of if statements, maybe [here](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-if-statements.php). You can also use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to help you debugging your scripts. Good luck.

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer, I think it'll also help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32119/using-regex-inside-if-clause-in-bash