# Regular expressions and wildcards in `if` statements

Tags: bash, regular-expression, wildcards

I am using regular expressions and wildcards in `if` statements.

Examples:

```
  [[ "$exitfn" =~ ^[yY]*$ ]] && return
  [[ "$exitfn" == "[yY]*" ]] && return
  [[ "$exitfn" == "*$fs*" ]] && return
  [[ "$exitfn" == *$fs* ]] && return
```

But really wonder about any difficulties introduced if I quote `*$fs*"` or do not quote `*$fs*`.

Also wondering about using `=~` against `==`.

Comment: Did you test those to see what differences there are? Also, see e.g. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/170373

Comment: also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32119/170373

Comment: Is the string in `$fs` a glob pattern (use unquoted with `==`), a regular expression (use unquoted with `=~`), or a literal string (use quoted with either `==` or `=~` depending on the rest of the pattern)?

Comment: `$fs` is not a glob pattern.

Answer (score 5):

The right-hand side of `==` or `!=` within `[[...]]` is a *glob pattern* -- `==` and `!=` are not string equality operators, they are *pattern matching* operators.

In a regex or a glob pattern, any quoted part is considered literal text.

```bsh
[[ "$exitfn" =~ ^[yY]*$ ]] && return
```

- this works as expected

```bsh
[[ "$exitfn" == "[yY]*" ]] && return
```

- this only returns if the variable is the literal text <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>

```bsh
[[ "$exitfn" == "*$fs*" ]] && return
```

- this only returns if the variable contains an asterisk followed by the contents of `$fs` followed by an asterisk

```bsh
[[ "$exitfn" == *$fs* ]] && return
```

- this should work as expected **unless** the expansion of `$fs` can be matched as a glob expression.

  - for example: if `fs='???'` then return will be executed if `$exitfn` contains at least 3 characters.

---

**tl;dr** -- you want

```bsh
  [[ "$exitfn" == *"$fs"* ]] && return
```